# EKEventStore access request crashes on iOS 10

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, ekeventstore

So, i'm working on a Xamarin project for mobile devices and i'm using the EKEventStore API for creating events and it's working fine on iOS 8 and 9.
But something went wrong while requesting EKEVentStore access on iOS 10.

The code below works fine on iOS 8 and 9, but on iOS 10 it crashes and no specific message is given for this error.

It seems that Apple has changed something about gathering this permissions in iOS 10.

Somebody had this same issue or knows something about that helps solving it?

Thanks!

```
EKEntityType type = EKEntityType.Event;
Store = new EKEventStore();
EKAuthorizationStatus status = EKEventStore.GetAuthorizationStatus(type);

if (status != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
{
    if (status == EKAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
    {    
        Store.RequestAccess(type, (bool granted, NSError error) =>
        {
            //Crashes before entering here
        });

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Denied
        return;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2016-09-30 17:16:25.739 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:    Native stacktrace:
2016-09-30 17:16:25.740 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   0   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0524e64d mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 317
2016-09-30 17:16:25.741 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   1   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x052a6321 sigabrt_signal_handler + 161
2016-09-30 17:16:25.741 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x07205ebb _sigtramp + 43
2016-09-30 17:16:25.742 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
2016-09-30 17:16:25.742 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   4   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x071e28bc abort_with_payload + 38
2016-09-30 17:16:25.743 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   5   TCC                                 0x003ab621 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 236
2016-09-30 17:16:25.743 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   6   TCC                                 0x003ab535 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 0
2016-09-30 17:16:25.743 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   7   TCC                                 0x003ae6b9 __tccd_send_block_invoke + 292
2016-09-30 17:16:25.744 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   8   libxpc.dylib                        0x0718c79c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 45
2016-09-30 17:16:25.745 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   9   libxpc.dylib                        0x07183a97 _xpc_connection_call_reply + 32
2016-09-30 17:16:25.746 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x06ea36ef _dispatch_client_callout + 14
2016-09-30 17:16:25.746 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x06e88c60 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 777
2016-09-30 17:16:25.747 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x06e8a4bc _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 384
2016-09-30 17:16:25.748 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x06e8a2d4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 134
2016-09-30 17:16:25.748 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x07215d6e _pthread_wqthread + 1070
2016-09-30 17:16:25.749 MyApp[3156:115989] critical:   15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0721591a start_wqthread + 34
2016-09-30 17:16:25.750 MyApp[3156:115989] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For events you will need to add the proper key in your info.plist, in this case would be `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` where the value is a short description of why are you requesting such permission.

Hope this solves your issue, I had exactly the same problem (also Xamarin) and this solved it.